# Cannot find module 'simple-plist'

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic Cordova app, and recently started getting this error:

```
(node:1897) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Cannot find module 'simple-plist'
```

What I've done:

- Removed ios and re-added
- Removed cordova and re-added
- Removed ionic and re-added
- Removed node_modules and re-added

It only shows up in package-lock.json as dependency for `cordova-ios`.

```
"simple-plist": {
      "version": "0.2.1",
      "bundled": true,
      "requires": {
        "bplist-creator": "0.0.7",
        "bplist-parser": "0.1.1",
        "plist": "2.0.1"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "base64-js": {
          "version": "1.1.2",
          "bundled": true
        },
        "plist": {
          "version": "2.0.1",
          "bundled": true,
          "requires": {
            "base64-js": "1.1.2",
            "xmlbuilder": "8.2.2",
            "xmldom": "0.1.27"
          }
        },
        "xmlbuilder": {
          "version": "8.2.2",
          "bundled": true
        }
      }
    },
```

...

```
"xcode": {
  "version": "0.9.3",
  "bundled": true,
  "requires": {
    "pegjs": "0.10.0",
    "simple-plist": "0.2.1",
    "uuid": "3.0.1"
  }
},
```

Comment: check path for `'simple-plist'` in project setting

Comment: ^ Added the information where `simple-plist` can be found.

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: The problem was it was somehow corrupted. I answered my question below. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

After trying the advice you gave, I received the same error when re-adding the ios platform. I was able to fix it by running the following command

```
npm install simple-plist
```

Comment: install the simple-plist works for me too, this should be marked as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem went away after I did the following steps:

- Roll back cordova to 7.1.0
- Remove`node_modules`
- Running `npm i`
- Deleted ios platform
- Re-added platform

Comment: I'm working through this problem right now. When re-adding the ios platform on step <Installing "ionic-plugin-keyboard" for ios> I receieve the same error "Cannot find module simple-plist"